# Wine: could not load file or assembly 'PresentationCore

Tags: software-installation, wine

when I attempt to run `wine Screenpresso.exe` I get this:

```
Main2
Wine: could not load file or assembly 'PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31b43856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
```

I can only click ok on the windows style error box. Re-running the install does not get past this.

The first install attempt mentioned that I needed wine mono to stand in for .NET, I okayed it. I do not get prompted for that again.

I'm using wine 4.0.1 on Lubuntu 18.04.

Any idea what causes this error?